# PHP MySQL query returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a basic PHP/MySQL test script.  When I attempt to print the two tables in the database I created ('andrew'), the PHP output returns none.  However, when I run the same command ('show tables;') through the MySQL 5.6 Command Line, both tables are returned.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='*****';
$database='andrew';
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else{echo 'Connected to MySQL! </ br>';}
$result=mysqli_query($connect,'show tables;');

if(!$result){
echo 'Nope';}
else{echo '<p>Result!!!</p>';}
echo '<p>Tables in database:</p>';
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
print_r ($row);}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: seems there's something wrong with your setup perhaps, I copy/pasted the code and added in my creds, and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Have you checked your user permissions? There is a specific permission for a "Show table" command, and is different from the "read" permission only

Comment: if i define $database as 'mysql', dozens of tables are returned.  But 'andrew' returns nothing.  When creating a new database, do I need any additional setup besides 'insert table', etc.?

Comment: Well the thing that gets me is why you are not seeing Nope printed to the page. Do you have other content on this page? If so does that display? If not and still getting white page, is there anything in the apache error log?

Comment: If you are not getting errors, that means that you are connecting properly, which makes me think that there is nothing on that table or something is missing on this question. Could you create a working example with some fake data in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Try run this sql in your mysql command line:

use mysql;
grant all on andrew.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'root password';

Then again try to run your script.

Answer (score 0):

The script you have is working properly.

**DETAILS**:

```
$host='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$database='test';
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Connected to MySQL!

Result!!!

Tables in database:

    Array ( [Tables_in_test] => tester )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='*****';
$database='andrew';
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
mysqli_select_db($connect,$database);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else {
    echo 'Connected to MySQL! </ br>';
}
$result=mysqli_query($connect,'your sql query');

if(!$result){
    echo 'Nope';
} else{
    echo '<p>Result!!!</p>';
}
echo '<p>Tables in database:</p>';
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
print_r($row);
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```